# HStack width changed when button label is changed

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

I created a HStack to include 3 buttons for TTS speaking control. However, when the middle button state is changed between play and pause. As the width of these 2 buttons is different I think, then the HStack width is changed accordingly.

How could I prevent this behavior to have a consistent width of HStack in this case?

[image]

```
struct HomeTest: View {
    @State private var isSpeaking: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 18) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .padding(6)
                    .foregroundStyle(.darkBlue10)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            Button {
                isSpeaking.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: (isSpeaking ? "pause" : "play"))
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .padding(6)
                    .foregroundStyle(.darkBlue10)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "goforward")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .padding(6)
                    .foregroundStyle(.darkBlue10)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 6)
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
        .background(.lightBlue10.opacity(0.7))
        .mask { Capsule() }
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 36)
                .inset(by: 1)
                .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a minimum width for this `Image`:

```swift
Button {
    isSpeaking.toggle()
} label: {
    Image(systemName: (isSpeaking ? "pause" : "play"))
        .frame(minWidth: 30) //<- set minWidth here
        .font(.system(size: 32))
        .padding(6)
        .foregroundStyle(.darkBlue10)
        .clipShape(Circle())
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice, could you explain how this works under the shell?

Comment: By default, min/max width/height is nil. This means the frame will have the sizing behavior of pause/play image. These frames are different in this scenario, let's say `play` will be 30x30 and `pause` will be 28x28. That's why you saw HStack's frame being toggled. Providing `minWidth` will make `pause` frame clamped to that minimum if its frame < minWdith. You can customize minWidth to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason you are facing the problem**: The `Image` for 'play' and 'pause' has different `width`. So when you change the button image by tapping the button then its outer wrapper view's size (width) also changes to fit the changed width Image of play/pause.

**Fix:** The conceptual fix for such a problem is: for an updatable view (In this case your play/pause `Image`) you should always use a fixed size to make the UI look consistent with different sized views.

For you code try this:

```swift
            Button {
                isSpeaking.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: (isSpeaking ? "pause" : "play"))
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30) // Follow your UX guide specification
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .padding(6)
                    .foregroundStyle(.darkBlue10)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
```